# Weird distribution of columns in tables

Tags: html, css

I'm quite inexperienced in all of this, but here's my problem. [The columns in my table are being distributed weirdly](https://liaundliam.ch/food/2016/11/27/sushi-rezept). I'm doing this using Squarespace (don't judge), but I can edit the CSS and insert costume code. For some reason the first column is taking up a lot more space than the rest.

Here's what I've done:

```css
.mytable {
  border: 0px solid #009688;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: block;  

  th {
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    height:50px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    background-color: #009688;
  }

  td {
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border:0px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
  }

  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #E0F2F1
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #fcfcfc
  }
  tr:hover {
    background-color: #1DE9B6
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Menge</th>
    <th>Bezeichnung</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100 g</td>
    <td>Geräucherter Lachs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 Stück</td>
    <td>Avocados</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 EL</td>
    <td>Zitronensaft</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>½ Stück</td>
    <td>Salatgurke</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 Stück</td>
    <td>Eier</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 EL</td>
    <td>Sesam</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>500 g</td>
    <td>Sushireis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 EL</td>
    <td>Zucker</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 EL</td>
    <td>Salz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 EL</td>
    <td>Reisessig</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10 Stück</td>
    <td>Noriblätter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 Stück</td>
    <td>Bambusmatte</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any suggestions? I should also add that I want the tables to be as responsive as possible (that's why I started playing with the CSS). Thanks!

Comment: You can use bootstrap to make your table responsive. also you can use bootstrap for table design.

Comment: What's the point of `width: 100%` on each `td`? This obviously can't work. You probably meant `50%`?

Comment: @jcaron removing that/setting it to `50%` leads to the table being narrower and white space appearing to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mytable {
  border: 0px solid #009688; 
  background-color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
  th {
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: left;
     height:50px;
     color: #eeeeee;
     background-color: #009688;
     width: 50%;
     }

   td {
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border:0px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 50%;
    }

   tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #E0F2F1
   }
   tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #fcfcfc
   }
   tr:hover {
    background-color: #1DE9B6
   }
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Menge</th>
    <th>Bezeichnung</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100 g</td>
    <td>Geräucherter Lachs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 Stück</td>
    <td>Avocados</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 EL</td>
    <td>Zitronensaft</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>½ Stück</td>
    <td>Salatgurke</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 Stück</td>
    <td>Eier</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 EL</td>
    <td>Sesam</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>500 g</td>
    <td>Sushireis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 EL</td>
    <td>Zucker</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 EL</td>
    <td>Salz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 EL</td>
    <td>Reisessig</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10 Stück</td>
    <td>Noriblätter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 Stück</td>
    <td>Bambusmatte</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This appears to break the responsiveness and i get overlapping text in tables with 4 columns. Should I define a class for each type of table (2 columns, 4 columns)?